# How to get a lastInsertID from one function and use it in another function? PDO

Tags: php

Hi I am able to get the last inserted ID in one function, but how am I able to use it in another function as it is being displayed as an undefined variable when outside of that function.

Thanks

EDIT:
code from class.user.php

```
public function one($first)
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO table1(first) VALUES(:first)");
            $stmt->bindParam(':first', $first);
            $stmt->execute();

            $newId = $this->db->lastInsertId();

            return $stmt;
            return $newId;

        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
           echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function two($array, $newID)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach($array as $arrayText){
                $this->db->beginTransaction();
                $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO table2(arrayText, table1_id) VALUES(:array, :newId)");
                $stmt->bindParam(':array', $arrayText);
                $stmt->bindParam(':newId', $newId);
                $stmt->execute();



                $this->db->commit();

            }

            return $stmt;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
           echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

php code

if(isset($_POST['btn']))
{
   $first = trim($_POST['first']);
   $array = $_POST['array'];


   if($user->one($first) && $user->two($array, $newId))
   {
       Print '<script>alert("Added to database");</script>'; //Prompts the user
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Return this value using `return` statement in the first function, then call this function in another. Example

```
<?php
function returnValue() {
    $someVar = 'hello';
    return $someVar; //or just 'hello' instead
}

function sayHello() {
    echo returnValue(); //or
    $helloText = returnValue(); // $helloText stores 'hello' string now
}
```

---

You cannot use two `return` statements one by one. In your code value of `$stmt` will be returned but `$newId` won't. If you want return 2 values you have to create an array.

eg.

```
<?php
return array($stmt, $newId);
```

In function two() now just call
`one($first)`

Comment: Wolen - my lastInsertID is saved as $newID which I am able to return in the first function. In the second function should I do $newID2 = functionOne($newID); ? Thanks

Comment: Can you show your code by editing first post? I will take a look on it and edit my answer then.

Comment: Wolen, whereabouts in function two do I call one($first)?

Comment: No matter, you can call function wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use return like this

```
<?php
function myfunction ()
{
    $var='My variable';
    return $var;
}

echo myfunction();
```