# Pass lastInsertId() in variable

Tags: php, pdo, lastinsertid

I get the last insertid with pdo in object1.php:

object1.php

```
class 1234{
    public function test{
        $query = "INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name . "
        SET uid=:uid, order_id=:order_id, position=:position, optionindex=:optionindex, created=:created";

        if($stmt->execute()){
            $last_id = $this->conn->lastInsertId(); 
        }
        print_r($last_id); //works here fine
        return true;
        }
    }
}
```

So next i need to pass $last_id in object2.php.

The only way it works for me, to use sessions ... but isn´t there a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: maybe call `test()` function from `object2.php` and get  `$last_id` as return result?

Comment: I don't think there is one general answer to that; it could be an object property, you could return it, etc. It all depends on the situation.

Comment: Instead of returning "true" return `lastInsertId()`. if the insert fails, lastInsertId will return 0 which can be read as false anyway.

Comment: I need to use the lastInsertID after the following call:

`if($object1->test()){
$_POST=array();
}`

here:

`query = "INSERT INTO media (last_id,....) VALUES('$last_id'....)";`

Both execute in the same post.

Comment: your query is incorrect. Is it a query for insert or update? Also, you can return the value then call the function for object2.php or you can also use global variables.

Comment: The query is for insert. I found similar post but i can´t get it to working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42459983/how-to-get-a-lastinsertid-from-one-function-and-use-it-in-another-function-pdo#42460016 ... seems like i farther use sessions. So store the lastinsert to `$_SESSION['last_id'] = $this->conn->lastInsertId();` after `$stmt->execute()` and pass it `$last_id = $_SESSION['last_id'];`